# Как при нажатии на кнопку сделать переход на следующий экран?

Tags: android, java

Пишу приложение для Android. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку осуществлялся переход на следующий экран?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Почитайте самые основы, а то далеко не уедете

http://megadarja.blogspot.cz/2008/10/android-2.html http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php

Answer (score 1):

```
startActivity(this, new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Comment: Эту строчку вставить в .java, а также создать новый класс SecontActivity.class? Можно чуть подробнее, я только учусь))

Comment: @Gorets, подозреваю, товарищ просит объяснить ему, что такое Java.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, в android studio это делается так - правой кнопкой мыши создаётся новая активность, после чего так же создаётся новый класс, кнопке присваевается событие onClick и ему присваеваевается имя класса, а в класс вставляется

```
    public void kyrsibtn(View view) {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, kyrsi.class);
    startActivity(intent);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создание активити по имени класса (может пригодится):

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
    String listNames[] = { "Test", "TestTest", "TestTestTest" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listNames));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
        String testName = listNames[position];
        try
        {
            Class<?> cl = Class.forName("com.example.myprog." + testName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, cl);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
        }

    }
```

ну, естественно, перед использованием надо создать активити Test, TestTest и TestTestTest и зарегать их в манифесте (просто напоминание):

```
 <activity android:label="Test" android:name=".Test" />
 <activity android:label="TestTest" android:name=".TestTest" />
 <activity android:label="TestTestTest" android:name=".TestTestTest" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра буду думать, как это всё реализуется.

Comment: @MDJHD, вряд ли товарищу это будет полезно. К тому же, если уж придраться, таким образом почти никто не поступает - используют намерения, если уж все так сложно.